# reading numbers from UIbutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I'm new in Objective-c and Xcode. I'm trying to get large numbers from certain buttons but all I got is only one number. I'm using button tag for that.

For instance: if I want to add two numbers 2+3, it works well. but when I want to add 230+32, it doesn't.

Interface :

```
- (IBAction)getnumber:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Result;
int number;
```

Implementation part:

```
-(IBAction)getnumber:(id)sender {
    number = [sender tag]; 
    Result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number]; 
}
```

Is there any way to get a large number from button's tag, if I tapped more than one button?

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from how you are defining your variables. If I understand your setup right, you have something like a calculator interface, and you are only setting button's tags to single digit numbers like 1, 2, 3, ... to indicate the next digit to display?

In that case your line `number = [sender tag]` will set a global variable to that button's number (remember when your CS prof told you never to use globals? Here's a reason why!) Since you just overwrote `number` with this button's tag when you go to set your result string in the next line, `number` only holds the value of the last button pressed. Instead you should do something like this.

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView * resultLabel;
- (IBAction)getNumber:(id)sender;
@end
```

and

```
- (IBAction)getNumber:(id)sender;
{
   self.resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", self.resultLabel.text, [sender tag]];
}
```

In this way, every time `getNumber:` is called, it takes whatever text the label is currently displaying and append's this button's value. As a side note, its conventional to start Objective-C property names with a lowercase letter.

Comment: After the above steps, to use it in operations, you need to take [resultLabel.text intvalue] or if decimal point is also pressed, [resultLabel.text floatvalue] to use it in mathematical operations ...

Comment: Yeah it is a calculator app. I tried to do as what you said and it works well but when I tried to add two numbers like 11+22 = I always get the first number at ahead of result 1133. Many thanks this helped me a lot.

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to do something like what utsabiem said above for the actual calculation, like store off the current value with `self.accumulator = [resultLabel.text integerValue]` when an operator is pressed then clear out the result `resultLabel.text = @""` and finally perform your math like `self.accumulator += [resultLabel.text integerValue]; resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.accumulator];`

Comment: I just simply used a variable instead of '[resultLabel.text integerValue]' and clean out the result with '[ NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c",' ']'. I will try what you and @utsabiem mentioned here. Obviously It's more efficient.

Comment: Is there any way instead of using '[sender tag]' to get 2 digits only ?

Comment: Hmm? Could you rephrase that? `sender.tag` is just an `int` you can assign to for more or less all purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to attach a variable type to `number`. It should be  -

```
- (IBAction)getnumber:(id)sender 
{
    NSInteger number = [sender tag]; 
    Result.text      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number]; 
}
```

I

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your logic.

number = 0;

if button with number is clicked

number = number * 10 + button.tag;

else

if operation (not =) is pressed

store the number and operator

if = operatior is clicked

perform the operation on stored number and recently entered number.

Comment: What the purpose of multiplication of the number by 10 ? Thanks for answering

Comment: @Michelle 520 means 5*100 + 2*10 + 0 so when ever you enter a number with this logic you can get exact number.

Comment: @Michelle : You can get as a string and convert into number but I think it's good if we do as numbers instead of strings.

Comment: I did as @axiixc said with a slight change and it worked. I saw some people use this way 'number = number * 10 + button.tag;' but to be honest I understand you but I didn't understand how this line would work with each time I tapped buttons.

Comment: @Michelle in `buttonClick` event or delegate.